# Finding sum of digits of a number until sum becomes single digit in python

Tags: python

I am writing a program that sums the digits in a number, until there is only one digit in the number. For instance:

Input: 92
9 + 2 = 11
1 + 1 = 2
Output: 2

My current code:

```py
number = int(input())
total_sum = 0
step = 1
condition = True
while condition:
    while number:
        total_sum += number%10
        number //= 10
    print("Step-%d Sum: %d" %(step, total_sum))
    number = total_sum
    total_sum = 0
    step += 1
    condition = number > 9
```

Comment: What do you call "direct output"?

Comment: Please provide more details about your problem. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Please provide a desired input and a desired output.

Comment: `number % 9 or 9 if number else 0`

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: in your code you just lost a '+' sign. substitute this line **"number = total_sum"** with **"number += total_sum"**. that all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive implementation, which uses memoization to speed things up:

```
from functools import cache

@cache
def f(n):
    sum_n = sum(map(int, str(n)))
    if sum_n > 9:
        return f(sum_n)
    return sum_n

print(f(92))
print(f(138))
```

produces

```
2
3
```

Comment: sum_n = sum(map(int, str(n)))  Thank you so much.can you explain this line.

Comment: `map(function, iterable)` applies `function` to each element of `iterable`. `sum(iterable)` sums the elements of iterable. So we apply the `int` function to each digit of the string representation of `n` to convert it from a string to an integer. Then we pass the results to `sum` to add them all up

Answer (score 0):

```
def sum_end(numb) :
    sum=0
    while numb>0 :
        rem=numb%10
        sum+=rem
        numb=numb//10
    if sum>9 :
        sum=sum_end(sum)
    return sum

print(sum_end(99999999999))
```

Comment: Don't use `sum` as a variable name.